# Dynamically adding divs through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding elements like `div` dynamically in the page using jquery.The `div` CSS is `position : absolute`   .Now my problem is when i add more than 1 div element at the same time than it all overlaps each other. Is there any way so that without changing my element's `position property` these are not overlaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out masonry plugin. It is dynamic layout plugin that auto arranges the div elements as the new elements are added in document it prevents the overlaps of the elements. Check out this [link.](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Simply specify the container div let it with id `container` you need to call function

```
$(".container").masonry();
```

and then when you add more div inside container you just need to call the function

```
var $newElems = $( newElements );
$(".container").masonry( 'appended', $newElems );
```

Answer (score 0):

You define place of absolutely positioned objects with top, bottom, left, right css properties . So you have to alter these dynamically as well.

For example: The first element has top: 0, left:0 , the second top: 0, left: 50 and so forth...

Comment: You will have to calculate the widths and heights and adjust the top and left accordingly for each div unless you want to change the position to relative.

Answer (score 0):

When you add an element as positioned absolute and provide no valid top and left values the element will be positioned absolutes with both top and left as 0.

In your case all the elements you are adding should be taking position (0,0) so they are overlapping one above other.

One solution is to calculate the positions of each and layout them using adding corresponding top and left values to them along sith css({'position' : 'absolute'}) but that requires some math in most cases.

Dont worry, your browser already knows that math and you can use it in most cases, so add the divs without 'position' 'absolute'. Now browser layouts them well. After the browser has finished laying out them, take the DIVs and get their present position and use the position to layout them using absolute position.

```
for(var i=0; i < noOfDivs; i++){
    {
    $('#parentDiv').append('<div class="childDiv"/>');
    }
$('.childDiv').css({
    'position': 'absolute,
    'top' : $(this).position().top,
    'left' : $(this).position().left
    });
```

The code is not tested, if DIVs are positioned one by one it should again cause problems, you should either iterate them from last to first or save all positions and apply them later. If jQuery is updating all positions in a single DOM access this will work fine.